# Python handling multiple exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I want to handle a specific exception in a certain way, and generically log all the others.
This is what I have:

```
class MyCustomException(Exception): pass


try:
    something()
except MyCustomException:
    something_custom()
except Exception as e:
    #all others
    logging.error("{}".format(e))
```

The problem is that even `MyCustomException` will be logged because it inherits from `Exception`. What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: How are you raising inside the `something()`? If it's raising a `MyCustomException` this code works properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What else is going on in your code?

`MyCustomException` should be checked and handled before flow ever gets to the second `except` clause

```
In [1]: def test():
   ...:     try:
   ...:         raise ValueError()
   ...:     except ValueError:
   ...:         print('valueerror')
   ...:     except Exception:
   ...:         print('exception')
   ...:         

In [2]: test()
valueerror

In [3]: issubclass(ValueError,Exception)
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 6):

Only the first matching except block will be executed:

```
class X(Exception): pass

try:
    raise X
except X:
    print 1
except Exception:
    print 2
```

only prints 1.

Even if you raise an exception in an except block, it won't be caught by the other except blocks:

```
class X(Exception): pass

try:
    raise X
except X:
    print 1
    0/0
except Exception:
    print 2
```

prints 1 and raises `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`